# Detect repeated characters using grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to write a grep (or egrep) command that will find and print any lines in "words.txt" which contain the same lower-case letter three times in a row. The three occurrences of the letter may appear consecutively (as in "mooo") or separated by one or more spaces (as in "x x x") but not separated by any other characters.

words.txt contains:

```
The monster said "grrr"!
He lived in an igloo only in the winter.
He looked like an aardvark.
```

Here's what I think the command should look like:

```
grep -E '\b[^ ]*[[:alpha:]]{3}[^ ]*\b' 'words.txt'
```

Although I know this is wrong, but I don't know enough of the syntax to figure it out. Using grep, could someone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
grep '\([[:lower:]]\) *\1 *\1'
```

It takes a lowercase character `[[:lower:]]` and remembers it `\( ... \)`. It than tries to match any number of spaces `_*` (0 included), the rememberd character `\1`, any number of spaces, the remembered character. And that's it.

You can try running it with `--color=auto` to see what parts of the input it matched.

Comment: yes that does work. I realize the significance of [[:lower:]] obviously, The \ before and after remembers it. *\1 means  a remembered character?

Comment: @BernieMacinflor: I added the explanation. `\1` means the first remembered character, `_*` means any number of spaces.

Comment: I used `_` instead of a space in explanations as I am not able to get a space into backquotes.

Comment: could you possibly have two remembered characters, and then use \2 to refer to the second remembered character?

Comment: @BernieMacinflor: Of course. See Backreferences in `man grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Note that this will not match "mooo", as the word boundary (`\b`) occurs before the "m".

`grep -E '\b([[:alpha:]]) *\1 *\1 *\b' words.txt`

`[:alpha:]` is an expression of a character class. To use as a regex charset, it needs the extra brackets. You may have already known this, as it looks like you started to do it, but left the open bracket unclosed.